# How can I Deserialize with Json.Net?

Tags: c#, serialization, interface, json.net

I'm trying to Deserialize json string to interface instance,

but my code returns exception message like
'Could not create an instance of type Form1+IFoo. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'value'

but anything I can't do?, I wanna solve this case, thanks.

here is code

```
    public interface IFoo
    {
        int value { get; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Foo : IFoo
    {
        public int value
        {
            get { return 1; }
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        IFoo foo = new Foo();

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo); //it's working
        IFoo dese = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IFoo>(json); //but it's not working
    }
```

Comment: What is wrong with `IFoo dese = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);`

Answer (score 2):

As interface and abstract classes cannot be instantiated.  You should use this,

```
     IFoo dese = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is straightforward, it's asking you not to give it an interface.  'Could not create an instance of type Form1+IFoo. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'value'

Try this please.

```
var dese = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json)
```

Comment: @L.B, Thank you for pointing that out, I've removed the offending part

Answer (score 1):

because the interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated
You can try this

```
IFoo dese = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IFoo>(json); //but it's not working
Foo dese = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json); //it'sworking
```