# How to transform a REST API response

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this code which returns a REST API response. How can I parse the JSON response to loop over the array of objects?

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var task = httpClient.GetAsync(url.ToString());
    var res = task.Result;
    res.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync();

    var resultTask = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    finalResponse = resultTask.Result;   // this is Json response

   // need to loop through the finalResponse??
}
```

My response structure from the REST API is as follows.

```
"result": [
    {
        “maxTry: 17,
        "minTry”: 10,
        "details": [
            {
                “firstName”: “Sam”,
            },
            {
                "firstName”: ”Julio”,
            }
        ],
        "aggr": [
            “Abc”,
        ],
        "zone": “D3”
    },
    {
        "aggr": [
            "Abc",
        ],
        "zone": “C3”
    },
    {
        "aggr": [
            "Abc",
        ],
        "zone": “B2”
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to _deserialize_ the JSON.

Comment: @Llama i tried this and its giving me something I am unable to loop through`var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(finalResponse);`

Comment: What classes you have created for this JSON? Can you share them please?

Comment: @Chetan i did not create any class yet

Comment: That's what you need to do then...

Comment: can you show the steps?

Comment: What are you trying to loop over and what is the response supposed to look like?

Comment: @xtc use https://json2csharp.com/ to create C# classes based on your JSON. Add those classes your code, deserialize JSON to class object and do your operation.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I Deserialize with Json.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722659/how-can-i-deserialize-with-json-net)

Comment: _"can you show the steps?"_ - Copy the JSON to clipboard. In Visual Studio go to the Edit menu, select Paste Special, and then Paste JSON as Classes. Or just make some C# classes that correspond to the structure of the JSON.

Comment: Your json is invalid and  you will never be able to parse or deserialize it. Pls post a valid real json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is to add the classes needed to `deserialize` Json data

```
public class JsonClass
{
   public List<JResult> Result { get; set; }
}
public class JResult
{
   public string MaxTry { get; set; }
   public string MinTry { get; set; }
   public List<Names> Details { get; set; }
   public List<string> Aggr { get; set; }
   public string Zone { get; set; }
}
public class Names
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Then download the data from the web using the following function.

```
private async Task<JsonClass> GetJsonData(string url)
{
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
       var result = await client.GetAsync(url);
       var response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonClass>(response);
   }
}
```

finally fetch data

```
 public JsonClass GetData(string url)
 {
     var data = Task.Run(() => GetJsonData(url)).Result;
     return data;
 }
```